# Adobe Flex pdf functionality

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, pdf-generation

I have a task of getting the snapshot of Adobe Flex application (imagine graphs, charts and tables) and produce the PDF file of it **from inside** of that same Flex application.

Imagine having a button that would do the screenshot and dump it into PDF file. Does anybody know the framework and/or component that would have such functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.alivepdf.org/ for an open-source client-side solution... See also http://www.rogue-development.com/blog2/2007/08/alivepdf-flexair-example/ etc.

You'll find a demo at http://blog.unthinkmedia.com/?p=53

The project source is at http://code.google.com/p/alivepdf/